# Adding hda/hdb device to android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, device, qemu, rootfs

I want to add a virtual hard disk & additional flash memory to android emulator

For that I created qemu raw images using below command:

```
qemu-img create internal.img 4G
qemu-img create internal-flash.img 4G
```

Then i made it ext4 type by below command:

```
mkfs.ext4 -F internal.img
mkfs.ext4 -F internal-flash.img
```

Now I am trying to load the newly created image as hda device in android emulator by below command:

```
./emulator -avd myandroid -qemu -hda internal.img -mtdblock internal-flash.img
```

Also, when i start my emulator the qemu emulator logs gets the images as arguments:

```
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-hda"
emulator: argv[02] = "/home/android-sdk/internal.img"
emulator: argv[03] = "-mtdblock"
emulator: argv[04] = "/home/android-sdk/internal-flash.img"
emulator: argv[05] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[06] = "/home/t0140899/.android/avd/SVDU4.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
```

But then I am not able to see /dev/hda in android file system
Could you please let me know if I need to do something more?

Also for additional additional flash memory where do i find it in /dev/ directory?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with this, but I'm not seeing a `mount` statement anywhere. You're creating the file systems, but where are you mounting it?

Comment: Thanks netinept, well, how do i mount as I do not get /dev/hda or /dev/block/hda device in android rootfs. I have a folder in Android which i need to mount it on hda and for which i created qemu image, but unless i get hda device in android file system, how do i mount that folder?